# Hibernate: OneToMany: удалить сторону One, но оставить Many.

Tags: jpa, hibernate, java

День добрый!

Использую JPA и Hibernate аннотации.

Есть Parent который содержит коллекцию Child. Надо удалить Parent, но не удалять его Childs.

Вот что я знаю об этом: 
- cascade определяет вызов какой функции будет повторен для потомка. например persist, delete итд. 
- если cascade не указан, то ничего не вызывается.

Однако с реальностью мои знания расходятся. Если я не пишу cascade, или если я перечисляю все операции кроме удаления - все равно удаляется все. Не помогает и использование хибернейтовского каскада.

Код:

```
@OneToMany()
//    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
//            org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST
//    )
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<Child> childs;
```

, unidirectional.

Я правильно понимаю использование cascade?
Как решить мою задачу?

Comment: Раз уж возникла такая задача, то нужно всех child перевести на другого parent. И тогда все будет так как нужно. А сирот оставлять - это плохо.

Comment: Почему? Допустим есть ряд проектов распределенных между менеджерами. При увольнении менеджера не обязательно проекты на кого-то сразу переводить. Может быть проект над которым никто не работает, это нормально.

Comment: А кто мешает создать "менеджера-анонима". Если человек уволился, то либо на анонима перекидывать, либо создавать временного менеджера-фантома.
В любом случае, ссылки на проекты нужно хранить, а то GC придет и сделает их своими.:)

Comment: Ну пусть GC придет, он же не заставит Hibernate удалить данные из таблицы. А менеджер-аноним это некий костыль и лишний код. Неужели нельзя без него? Задача-то тривиальная.

Comment: А не думали о том, что сам движок базы данных может все удалять для поддержания каскадной целостности?
Задача тривиальная, но решаете ее через одно место.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге у меня был какой-то глюк, видимо действительно старый cascade в базе. Вот такая простая конструкция решает поставленную задачу:

```
@OneToMany()
// or @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private Set<Project> actions;
```

При удалении владельца такой коллекции ее объекты не удалятся, как и должно быть.

По итогам хочу уточнить 2 вопроса:

1) правильно ли я понял, что аннотации cascade никакого отношения к каскадам БД не имеют и действуют только при вызове соотв. им функций?

2) если да, то можно ли как-то через аннотации воздействовать на каскады в constraints БД?